# Change Package Name after implementation of data binding

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, package

I'm using **Databinding** with one of my project with project name **com.abc.def**. I've related all my views with binding like

```
ActivityLoginBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login);
```

it worked fine but if I change my package name to **com.Abc.Def**  it generated following error at the time of building Apk.

> Cause: couldn't make a guess for
>   com.Abc.Def.databinding.ActivityLoginBindingImpl .

**Please Note**:

1. I have an old build with  com.Abc.Def on playstore already live and I'm updating the version. That's why I have to Change package name.
2. I can't remove Databinding from whole project.as it relates to all views.
3. If I change my package name to old one ,it works fine.

I have already tried **clean , rebuild and invalidate cache and restart** .but no luck.

Comment: Hey Tejas, did you find the solution, I'm kinda facing the same issue.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I just bumped into the same issue. I was able to **fix it by toggling databinding.enabled inside Build.gradle (Module)**. Below is a little step-by-step guide, that I went through after renaming my company package (com.**abc**.myapp -> com.**xyz**.myapp), which got databinding to work as expected:

---

1. *Build > Clean Project*
2. go to your *Build.gradle (Module)* and **disable databinding**:

   `android {
        dataBinding {
            enabled = false
        }
   }`
3. *File > Sync Project with Gradle Files*
4. *Build > Rebuild Project* (no surprise: you'll get a ton of error messages)
5. Now **enable databinding** again:

   `android {
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
   }`
6. *File > Sync Project with Gradle Files*
7. *Build > Rebuild Project*

---

Note: Some steps here may be unnecessary, but a little extra sanity checking has never done any harm during project setup, right!?

Comment: This works, but I just want to add that, If you're using Navigation Components you better double check on your nav_graph file if there is no trace of your previous package name

Comment: I followed these steps but result was same, after this restarting Android Studio fixed the errors

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: tried this process but I still has same error :(

Comment: @DoilioMatsinhe you are awesome bro <3

Comment: For those who did not worked , Try to rename last package folder and revert again , Then try this , Also don't forget to press re build on each step

Answer (score 3):

According to JAVA package naming conventions: 
The package name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters[a-z], numbers, and underscores [ _ ].
You can not use capital letters in naming packages.

Comment: but as i've mentioned in my question . I already have one build with capital letters . `com.Abc.Def` . So Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

```
com..Abc.Def.databinding.ActivityLoginBindingImpl .
```

Check if there is no empty package there, for those `..`

Comment: I'm sorry Max . its typo . my bad . updated question .

Answer (score 1):

first of all, did you changed package name only in Manifest?
note that it could be different to `applicationId` - so you can only change it and leave app package as it was.

**RCA:** probably OS you are using to build is case-insensitive but java compiler is - that's reason why it can't find classes. Bindings are generated alongside other generated classes (for example dagger 2 classes generated by annotation processor), each generator creates own files within folder structure that reflects class package **BUT if packages differ only with big/small letters, second generator will use same folder with wrong name**. The reason is if OS is case-insensitive it assumes that folder already exist but java compiler not.

Other solution (except leaving app package as it is) is to :

- rename all packages in app to other that differ to app package or to
  use OS that is case-sensitive (macOS could be formatter this way or
  linux)

Comment: I couldn't understand  . I'm using Windows for Android Studio and I've replaced the package name from the whole project module

Comment: just to confirm - you've changed :
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    **package="com.abc.def**">,`
all databinding classes should be generated with this package.

what is you app module package (I mean all your classes are in this one)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, After spending several hours had to change the name of the layout to make it work.

Steps I followed to make it work.

1. Tried clean build, invalidate cache, enable/disable binding. ( didn't work)
2. Got a suggestion from one of my fellow developer to recreate and rename the XML file.  (It worked) !!

Answer (score 0):

I`ve encountered this one also. If ever Basti Vagabond Instruction did not work try to search the entire files.

Just Follow this instruction below:

**Edit->Find->Replace in Files** *(then search the old package name and replace it with your new package name).*

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check and confirm package names are changed for namespace and applicationId at build.gradle(app level).

android {

```
namespace 'new package name'
compileSdk 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "new package name"
    }
  }
```