# Databinding generated in the wrong package

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, android-databinding

I have several modules in my project and I've renamed one of them (including the packages). This module is an Android Library module with `databinding` enabled.
After the renaming, the `ActivityBindingImpl` file is generated in the old package.
The `BR` and `DataBinderMapperImpl` files are generated in the new package like this:

```
module
 -- java (generated)
 ---- old.package
 ------ ActivityBindingImpl
 ---- new.package
 ------ BR
 ------ DataBinderMappingImpl
```

Then I get the expected a build error:

> ActivityBindingImpl.java:2: error: cannot find symbol import old.package.BR

The package in the `Manifest` file is correct.

I've tried to clean the project, invalidate Android Studio cache, disable/enable `databinding` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59571662/2318632) but nothing worked.

Edit:

```
kapt {
    useBuildCache = false
}
```

Also didn't help :(

Answer (score 2):

Adding `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4"` to the `build.gradle` fixed the issue. Don't know why exactly.

Answer (score 2):

#### Steps

**Step 1.**

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding false
}
```

**Step 2.**  Sync your project

**Step 3.** Clean and rebuild your project

**Step 4.**

```
 buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

**Step 5.**  Again Sync your project

**Step 6**. Clean and rebuild your project

it's work for me!

Comment: It was so obvious, but... Thanks!